# What is the purpose of "vocabulary" as tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 20 questions using [vocabulary](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), but the tag doesn't have a description.

What should the purpose of the tag be? Does it make sense when there are tags like [single-word-requests](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), [word-choice](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) and [word-usage](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has a purpose. We should remove it as some people are using it instead of the more precise tags.